# Making a sequential list of files

Tags: c++

I have been stuck on a problem for a while now and can't seem to find an answer.
I'm trying to create multiple files with the same name but a different number at the end each time, I have attempted this at first just by using

```
int seq_number = 1;
while (seq_number < 10)
{
ofstream fsave;
fsave.open("filename" + seq_number + ".txt");
fsave << "blablabla";
fsave.close();
seq_number = seq_number + 1;
}
```

But that gives me a very strange result where the letters get jumbled up, I'm not sure how that works but I know it doesn't.

I've looked online and found stringstream or sstream, and tried with that, but it keeps giving me errors too,

```
string filename;
filename = "character";
ostringstream s;
s << filename << seq_number;
filename(s.str());
fsave.open(filename + ".txt");
fsave << "blabla"
fsave.close(;)
```

but i keep getting an error:

no match for call to `(std::string) (std::basic_string, std::allocator >)'

I'm not sure how string stream works exactly so im working off of instinct, but i would appreciate any way this is possible, and honestly I think I would prefer doing it without sstream, but i need a way to get an int and str together and save a filename that is a string.
unless you know a better way ;) thanks guys

Comment: `filename(x)` syntax can only be used when constructing the string. Afterwards you use `=` syntax. If you change that, your code should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
filename(s.str());
```

this is wrong; you are not constructing a new variable (`filename` is already constructed), what you want here is an assignment.

```
filename = s.str();
```

Then,

```
fsave.open((filename + ".txt").c_str());
```

(although, if you are using C++11, this change is not necessary)

Still, personally I would just construct the whole file name with the stream:

```
ostringstream s;
s<<"character"<<seq_number<<".txt";
fsave.open(s.str.c_str());
```

> I'm not sure how string stream works exactly so im working off of instinct

This is a very bad idea, C++ is often quite a minefield of bizarre syntax, segfaults and undefined behavior, going by instinct usually leads to disaster.

---

About the errors you get:

```
fsave.open("filename" + seq_number + ".txt");
```

This shouldn't even compile, since you are summing an integer to a `const char *` (thus moving the "start of the string"), and then summing it again to a `const char *`, which is not allowed at all. Maybe it could compile if it were like this:

```
fsave.open("filename" + seq_number);
```

but it won't give the required result - `"filename"` is a pointer (not a C++ string), so summing an integer to it just moves the pointer of the given offset.

In your second snippet, instead, you are using an object (`filename`) as it were a function, which is only allowed if the class overloads `operator()`; thus, the compiler complains that such an operation is not allowed on that object.

Comment: thank you for an amazing explanation, and yes i know testing by doing is a bad idea in coding, i just do my best until i can't figure it out, which was now so i asked for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
fsave.open(filename + ".txt");
```

With

```
fsave.open( (filename + ".txt").c_str() );
```

This is because the `ofstream` constructor takes as parameter a `char const *`, not an `std::string`.

Also, your first version generates strange file names because in C and C++, adding an integer to a `char *` simply offsets within the character array. It does not append to the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
ostringstream s;
s << "character" << seq_number << ".txt";
fsave.open(s.str());
fsave << "blabla";
fsave.close();
```

And this is how you could implement the original loop:

```
for (int seq_number = 1; seq_number<10; ++seq_number) 
{
    ostringstream s;
    s << "filename" << seq_number << ".txt";
    ofstream fsave(s.str());
    fsave << "blablabla";
}
```

Comment: Note that this requires C++11 support in the Standard Library implementation. If it complains, use `fsave.open(s.str().c_str());`.

Comment: One day we will be able to stop adding these sorts of qualifiers. One day. Soon? Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can not convert an `int` to a string, or concatenate it to one -- not to a ´char*`:

```
"filename" + seq_number + ".txt"
^const char*    ^int      ^const char*
```

Also, `ostream` can not recieve the filename as a `string`, it must be a `const char*`, which you can acquire temporarily via ´c_str()`.

Use `sprintf`, `ostringstream` (as you did), or C++11 `to_string` to do that:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    for(int seq_number = 1; i<10; ++i) {
        std::string num_as_string = std::to_string(seq_number);  // make a string, C++11
        std::string filename = "abcd" + num_as_string + ".txt";
        std::ostream f(filename.c_str());
        f << "text\n";
   }
}
```

This (modulo typos) should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    std::string filename;
    int seq_number = 10;
    filename = "character";
    std::stringstream s;
    s << filename << seq_number << ".txt";
    filename = s.str();
    std::cout<< filename << std::endl; // <-- Here open your file instead print the filename
}
```